# How do I encrypt a file with gnupg and php?

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg, pgp

I am not a PGP expert and php isn't my first language, so I am having some trouble using gnupg to encrypt a file. I can get it to encrypt strings just fine.

If I use PGPTool (windows) to encrypt my file and then open it in a text editor it looks like binary data...

```
…]/…D2Øþ3EaÚj'ƒ‚Ì
4aœ¶è[Šæ³7=q    [Ûµ|<j‘«™yÅÊ§Ê[¥å¾•§Ù³,–rnÃÆ¦â…–iüïÛµèCŠ
```

If I read in the file and encrypt it with gnupg i get a plain text result, as if it were to be pasted into an email.

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)

hQMOAx1dL4VEMtgUEAv/cOuJDBZ8FIYk7kqsh2vOvW2WRUvOUi54xm1LPGxLPiMS
```

My problem is, I need it to be output as the first option for sending to a specific client. Is there a way to get gnupg and php to do this?

Comment: It looks like the output is just base64 encoded, is there a way to tell gnupg to not base64 encode after it encrypts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to the PHP-manpages (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-setarmor.php) the **default** output is a text file with base64 encoded data:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)
hQMOAx1dL4VEMtgUEAv/cOuJDBZ8FIYk7kqsh2vOvW2WRUvOUi54xm1LPGxLPiMS
...
```

Using the gnupg-setarmor function you can set the output to a binary output:

```
gnupg_setarmor($res,0);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
// init
$res = gnupg_init();
// # add this line
gnupg_setarmor($res,0); // deactivate default armored output
gnupg_addencryptkey($res,"8660281B6051D071D94B5B230549F9DC851566DC");
$enc = gnupg_encrypt($res, "just a test");
echo $enc;
?>
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks. Just for completeness for any future readers if you are using the "$gpg = new gnupg()" style the answer would be "$gpg -> setarmor(0);"